# Modify chapter heading to be used in report class

Tags: sectioning, memoir, chapters, report

How do I convert the following from memoir class to report class? I'm currently writing a dissertation in report class and it would be great if I could use this chapter heading:

```
\usepackage{fourier} % or what ever
\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}%. Sans serif - Helvetica
\usepackage{color,calc}
\newsavebox{\ChpNumBox}
\definecolor{ChapBlue}{rgb}{0.00,0.65,0.65}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\thickhrulefill}{%
    \leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 1\p@ \hfill \kern \z@}
\newcommand*\BuildChpNum[2]{%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
        \makebox[0pt][c]{#1\strut}           \\[.5ex]
        \colorbox{ChapBlue}{%              
        \rule[-10em]{0pt}{0pt}%            
        \rule{1ex}{0pt}\color{black}#2\strut 
        \rule{1ex}{0pt}}%                  
    \end{tabular}}
\makechapterstyle{BlueBox}{%
    \renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\large\scshape}
    \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\Huge\bfseries}
    \renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\raggedright\Huge\bfseries}
    \setlength{\beforechapskip}{20pt}
    \setlength{\midchapskip}{26pt}
    \setlength{\afterchapskip}{40pt}
    \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}
    \renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}
    \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{%
        \sbox{\ChpNumBox}{%
            \BuildChpNum{\chapnamefont\@chapapp}%
            {\chapnumfont\thechapter}}}
    \renewcommand{\printchapternonum}{%
        \sbox{\ChpNumBox}{%
            \BuildChpNum{\chapnamefont\vphantom{\@chapapp}}%
            {\chapnumfont\hphantom{\thechapter}}}}
    \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
    \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
        \usebox{\ChpNumBox}\hfill
        \parbox[t]{\hsize-\wd\ChpNumBox-1em}{%
            \vspace{\midchapskip}%
            \thickhrulefill\par
            \chaptitlefont ##1\par}}%
}
\chapterstyle{BlueBox}
```

I'm still newbie in Latex that's why I'm asking for help this way

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: As always please provide a full minimal example, not just a sniplet. That makes it a lot easier for others to help

Comment: Why do you need it to be in the report class? Add the `openany` class option to `memoir` and it behaves like `report`

Comment: @daleif you mean `oneside`.

Comment: @touhami no, but you are right, report does load `oneside`, I just think `openany` is more in the spirit of `report`, it is porobably being printed twoside anyway.